# NetworkManager: nm_setting_gsm_get_pin returns NULL

Tags: c++, linux, networkmanager

I'm trying to use libnm to communicate with NetworkManager from a custom application. But I've run into a problem.

Whenever I try to read the configured PIN code using `nm_setting_gsm_get_pin`, NULL is returned. I have a feeling something more needs to be done since when using nmcli, we must pass the --show-secrets flag to see the PIN code. There might be something similar in libnm. But I cannot find it.
I'm running my application with sudo, so access rights should not be an issue.
I can read the PIN code using `sudo nmcli -s con show MOBILE`, so I know it's there.

I have the following code:

```
NMClient *client = nm_client_new (NULL, NULL);

const GPtrArray * allConnections = nm_client_get_connections(client);
allConnections = nm_client_get_connections(client);

g_ptr_array_foreach((GPtrArray *)allConnections,
    [](gpointer connection, gpointer user_data) {

        std::string thisId = nm_connection_get_id((NMConnection*)connection);

        if(thisId == "MOBILE") {
            MobileConnection = (NMConnection*)connection;
        }

    },
    nullptr);

NMSettingGsm *GsmSettings = nm_connection_get_setting_gsm(MobileConnection);
if(GsmSettings != nullptr) {

    bool autoConf = nm_setting_gsm_get_auto_config(GsmSettings);
        std::cout << "Auto APN: " << (autoConf  ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;
    }

    const char *PinCh = nm_setting_gsm_get_pin(GsmSettings);
    if(PinCh != nullptr) {
        std::string PinString = PinCh;
        std::cout << "PIN: " << PinString << std::endl;
    } else
        std::cout << "No PIN found" << std::endl;
}
```

The above code can read the auto config parameter just fine, so I know the `NMSettingGsm *GsmSettings` is OK. But it always print "No PIN found".